# settings.groovy not read by grails-maven-plugin

Tags: authentication, maven, grails, settings, grails-maven

I have a Grails application that has depencencies in MavenRepos that need authentication.
Therefore I've set the following property in my **settings.groovy**.

```
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    credentials {
        realm = "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
        host = "testnexus.testserver.com"
        username = "testuser123"
        password = "password123"
    }
}
```

When building using Grails, this works fine. The credentials are read, the Nexus query gets authenticated, dependencies are downloaded.

Since my application is part of a larger project that uses Maven for dependency management, I'm using the grails-maven-plugin for integrating my application in the larger project, so that I can keep my BuildConfig.groovy while the larger project maintains its pom.xml file for the build.

When using calling **mvn package**, I see how it triggers the grails plugin, which starts my build. However the settings.groovy is not read and because of that I won't be able to resolve all dependencies.

```
try to get credentials for: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@testnexus.testserver.com
authentication: k='Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@testnexus.testserver.com' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=https://testnexus.testserver.com/nexus/content/groups/public/...
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=https://testnexus.testserver.com/nexus/content/groups/public/...
```

When adding the credentials in **BuildConfig.groovy** it works fine, but that would not be a solution.

**How can I configure the grails-maven-plugin to read settings.groovy or where can I declare these credentials to that the grails-maven-plugin reads it?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to create maven settings, the authentication model is not the same.

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html